# Geocode mapping - a couple of questions

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer

A couple of troubleshooting questions regarding Geocode mapping.

One, it is problematic doing Geocode mapping in IE ( I use version 11), as a JSON error results, even tough the mapping itself seems to work, but with the error "Unable to get the property  'sa' of undefined or null reference.  Is there some sort of setting in IE that prevents this?  Or is it just a matter of using a different browser, which never seem to have this error?  No skin off my nose, but a lot of my customers use IE and I'm hoping to avoid telling them to switch.

Also, Geocoding makes use of the API Key, of course.  I have this key embedded in my javascript.  Is this a safe practice, or do these keys ever "expire" for lack of a better term?  I'm trying to avoid the potential problem of the geocoding suddenly failing to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Compatibility View on?  It's not supported by the Maps JS API. If that's not it, maybe post the part of your javascript that's throwing the error.

As far as your keys - you should be able to restrict the key in the Google API console ([Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard) > Credentials > click the key name) - in your case it's probably best to use HTTP referrers and set your website's domain

[image]

Comment: Thanks much for the information - very helpful.  Yes, out of necessity we have Compatibility View on.  We are planning to upgrade to .Net 4.5 in January; I'm told Compatibility View is necessary until then. In the meantime, I don't suppose anyone knows if there is a way to somehow suppress the error "Unable to get the property 'sa' of undefined or null reference." that pops up in Internet Explorer?  I'm guessing not, but perhaps there is a way.